# DataTable sorting (A number should be higher priority than a letter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery [DataTable](http://datatables.net/) for data grid. I need help for sorting a column value that might be a combination of letters and numbers. I have to give priority to the number before the letters when sorting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

In this example for column `Browser` the result for `ASC` order should be like:

```
abc21
bbc22
abc23
bbc26
abc29
abc31
```

Sorting by number first.

[Code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZL5kL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Formatted Numbers` custom sort plugin, which can be found on [Datatables Plugin Section](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting)

Essentially, you call the code below when sorting that column.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a === "-" || a === "") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
    },

    "formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```

You tell datatables to use this sort by setting the `aoColumns` object in your init code for your table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "aoColumns": [
                null, // each of these = a column in your table
                null,
                null,
                // this column, 4th, will be sorted usig the plugin
                { "sType": "formatted-num-pre" }, 
                null
            ]
        } );
    } );
```

There is also a `Natural sorting` plugin on that same page that may help.

Ultimately, you can create your own plugins by following the examples.